# UTF-8 error while adding data to postgresql with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, pgadmin-4

```
import io
import csv
import datetime 
import psycopg2
import glob

conn = psycopg2.connect("host= 127.0.0.1 dbname=postgres user=postgres password=123 client_encoding='utf8' ")

f = io.StringIO()
w = csv.writer(f)


f.seek(0)
cursor = conn.cursor()

cursor.copy_expert(f""" COPY ama3 FROM 'C:/abc/asd.csv'  (FORMAT CSV)""", f)

conn.commit()
```

**ERROR: CharacterNotInRepertoire: ERROR: Invalid byte sequence for language encoding "UTF8":**

The csv file contains letters containing "ş,i,ö,Ğ,İ". I think the error is caused by this, but I don't want to change them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not adding the data from ptyhon, you are adding it directly from the filesystem using PostgreSQL's `copy` command. Make sure your csv file is UTF-8 encoded.

While in linux/mac you can easily do a:

```
$ file /abc/asd.csv
```

In Windows is not that straightforward (I am assuming you are using Windows).

In windows, you could:

Open up your file using regular old vanilla Notepad that comes with Windows. It will show you the encoding of the file when you click `Save As...`.

[image]

If it's not in UTF-8, convert it and try running your script again.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm getting a copy error due to empty spaces in my csv file and I'm separating it with my csv mi (delimiter "#")
empty fields (# #) appear in my data